# how to make a div appear on hover and disappear on hover out?

Tags: javascript, menu, hover, toggle

hi first of all this is my code -

```
<script>
function slide() {
    if(document.getElementById('eiv').className == 'deactive') {
        document.getElementById('eiv' ).className = 'active';
        document.getElementById('eiv').style.webkitTransition ='all 0.5s';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("eiv").className = 'deactive';
        document.getElementById('eiv').style.webkitTransition ='all 0.5s';
    }
}
function slideout() {
    if(document.getElementById('eiv').className == 'active') {
        document.getElementById('eiv' ).className = 'deactive';
        document.getElementById('eiv').style.webkitTransition ='all 0.5s';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("eiv").className = 'active';
        document.getElementById('eiv').style.webkitTransition ='all 0.5s';
    }
}
</script>
<body>
<span id="container"><div id="colo" onmouseover="slide()" onmouseout="slideout()">lololol</div>
</body>
```

i made a div by the id eiv which slides on left side on hover of colo and slides back out on mouseout from colo , this all is fine but i want that after making it appear it should stay there when we mouseover on eiv and slide out on mouseout from eiv( when eiv slides in it will overlap colo) and then when you again mouse in on colo then eiv appears

this is somewhat like the charmsbar in windows 8

Comment: Please mark one answer as accepted so you can help other people.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, because if your div become hide, you never trigger hover event.

So I suggest that you change of the color div to the same color of the background-color of your site or change to transparent.

```
.visibleDiv{
  background-color:yellow;
  height:100px;
  display:block;
}
.visibleDiv:hover{
  background-color:white;
  height:100px;
  display:block;
}
```

See the [example](http://jsbin.com/orANoNE/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then this might help you.

You can create something using JQuery and hover. This way.

You have to have an element outside the div you want to hide.

In this example, I use `div="target1"` as an outside element to hide 
the `div="msg1"`

```
<div id="target1">Hover here for .hover()</div>
<div id="msg1"></div>

$("#target1").hover(function () {
    $("#msg1").toggle();
});
```